# How can I use the Feed Dialog to post in friend's wall?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, feed

I use FB.ui with feed method in order to post a message in an user's wall.

```
   // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      to: 123457895,
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };
```

But is it possible to post in severals friend's wall in one time with feed dialog method?

I tested to put severals IDs in to element but it seeems that it don't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hate to contradict what superscral said but you can use the "to:" parameter for the feed method. Check here for a list of currently supported parameters:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: So would it be possible to use the `to` parameter to post to several walls at once?  Or would that require FB Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

Feed Dialog allows users to post a message only to their own timeline which would then appear on their friends' News Feeds/Stream.